Rのkernlabで、kernel matrixからSVMを行ったときの不具合について
ガウシアンカーネルを用いていますが、説明変数からSVMを行った場合と、カーネル行列からSVMを行った場合で結果が異なります。どうしてこのような違いが生じるかわかりません。
data(spam)
index <- sample(1:dim(spam)[1])
spamtrain <- spam[index[1:2000],]
spxx <- as.matrix(spamtrain[, 1:57])
stype <- spamtrain$type
spam.svm <- ksvm(spxx, stype, kernel="rbfdot", kpar=list(sigma=0.05), C=5, cross=3, scale=T)
error(spam.svm)  # 0.014
cross(spam.svm)  # 0.07649404
rbf <- rbfdot(sigma=0.05)
Kspam <- kernelMatrix(rbf, scale(spxx))
spam2.svm <- ksvm(Kspam, stype, C=5, cross=3)
error(spam2.svm)  # 0.145
cross(spam2.svm)  # 0.1175433


kernel matrix computation outside SVM training in kernlab
の回答の最初の部分に

kernlab appears to treat the calculation of ksvm differently when explicitly using vanilladot() because it's class is 'vanillakernel' instead of 'kernel'.

とあるので，恐らく rbfdot() を使った場合もクラスが "rbfkernel" になり，ksvm() での計算に少し手を加えられていると考えられます。
試しに rbfdot() を使ってクラスを "kernel" に再設定すると両者のサポートベクターのインデックスは一致するようになりました。なお，rbfdot() を使わずに関数を直接定義し（クラスを "kernel" に設定して）両者で使っても同様の結果でした。
library(kernlab)

rbf = rbfdot(sigma=0.05)
class(rbf)
## [1] "rbfkernel"
## attr(,"package")
## [1] "kernlab"
class(rbf) <- "kernel"

set.seed(123)
data(spam)
index <- sample(1:dim(spam)[1])
spamtrain <- spam[index[1:2000], ]
spxx <- as.matrix(spamtrain[, 1:57])
stype <- spamtrain$type

set.seed(123)
(spam.svm <- ksvm(spxx, stype, kernel=rbf, scaled=TRUE, C=5, cross=3))
## Support Vector Machine object of class "ksvm" 
## 
## SV type: C-svc  (classification) 
##  parameter : cost C = 5 
## 
## 
## Number of Support Vectors : 824 
## 
## Objective Function Value : -984.9425 
## Training error : 0.053 
## Cross validation error : 0.164468

set.seed(123)
Kspam <- kernelMatrix(rbf, scale(spxx))
(spam.svm2 <- ksvm(Kspam, stype, C=5, cross=3))
## Support Vector Machine object of class "ksvm" 
## 
## SV type: C-svc  (classification) 
##  parameter : cost C = 5 
## 
## [1] " Kernel matrix used as input."
## 
## Number of Support Vectors : 824 
## 
## Objective Function Value : -984.9425 
## Training error : 0.053 
## Cross validation error : 0.164468

identical(SVindex(spam.svm), SVindex(spam.svm2))
## [1] TRUE

